# How to convert CSV to JSON with requires one line in CSV file will export one file JSON

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a problem and need a help from you!
I want to convert CSV to JSON,and 1 line in CSV with export 1 file JSON (JSON's content is CSV line's content,and JSON's name is id of this line).
I try to do,but it's only display and download JSON.
Please give me a suggestion for this problem.
Thanks for your help!

> ```
> <?php
>
> header('Content-type: application/json');
>
> $feed = 'jsondata_palpad.csv';
>
> $keys = array();
> $newArray = array();
>
> function csvToArray($file, $delimiter) { 
>   if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) { 
>     $i = 0; 
>     while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter, '"')) !== FALSE) { 
>       for ($j = 0; $j < count($lineArray); $j++) { 
>         $arr[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; 
>       } 
>       $i++; 
>     } 
>     fclose($handle); 
>   } 
>   return $arr; 
> } 
>
> $data = csvToArray($feed, ',');
>
> $count = count($data) - 1;
>
> $labels = array_shift($data);  
>
> foreach ($labels as $label) {
>   $keys[] = $label;
> }
>
> $keys[] = 'id';
>
> for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
>   $data[$i][] = $i;
> }
>
> for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
>   $d = array_combine($keys, $data[$j]);
>   $newArray[$j] = $d;
> }
>
> header("Content-type: application/json");
> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.json");
> header("Expires: 0");
> header("Pragma: no-cache");
> echo json_encode($newArray);
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? What is the problem specifically? Stackoverflow is [not](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help5) a code-writing service.

Comment: I tried,but don't know how to do,please help me!

Comment: Please construct a small sample output. It's not really clear what the input structure is, nor if you want the columns/rows in one JSON output, or in distinct files as your question mentioned.

Comment: Here is sample that i found: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqd4iwcm47epthd/palpad_contents_web_001_001.json   https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw4nm8aqphdb7g2/jsondata_palpad.csv

Comment: I want to do the same like that,will you help me?

Comment: I just want a suggestion to complete my task. Can you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a titled CSV file.

To read it, first convert the rows into an array:

```
 $csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($filename));
 $head = array_shift($csv);
```

For conversion into an associative array:

```
 $csv = array_map("array_combine", array_fill(0, count($csv), $head), $csv);
```

To generate the files:

```
 foreach ($csv as $index => $row) {

     file_put_contents("$index.json", json_encode($row));

 }
```

Here the loop counter `$index` is used for generating the filenames.

See the manual for explanations on:

- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map)
- [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv)
- [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

If you did want something else, write a more precise question next time.